# jQuery and WordPress (Version 3.3.2)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've added a new JavaScript file to the js directory in my custom theme and referenced it in header.php within the header block like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/myScript.js"></script>
```

The content of the js file is to test a jQuery alert:

```
(function($) {

  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('ready');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I've tried multiple no-conflict solutions and my script is still ignored. I'm stumped, has anyone else fixed this? I've looked at a few different solutions from the past few years and they all seem to be bunko now.

I've even tried this within header.php before my script:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm blocked for now.

Comment: Can you see if firebug or your javascript error console says anything? What you have should work. Are you linking jQuery before your script?

Comment: Yes, I've been using firebug and it's all there, just not executing with the DOM. I'll try any answers I receive from this query tonight and see if anything works. I'm a sad panda right now.

Comment: it's hard to know without looking at your specific case. You can email me if you want to solve it in private (if you do not want to disclose your site).

Comment: Sorry, guys. It turned out to be a broken set of variables that accompanied the alert. The above works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(function() {

      alert('ready');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    alert('ready');
  });
```

do not use `(function($) {})(jQuery);`